# Not able to access OpenSIPS CP web interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, sip, vmware-workstation, opensips

I have installed opensips-2.1.2 in on vmware (ubuntu 14.4.6).
I can see opensips installation went fine, but not able to access the web interface for the same.

After installation i have greped the process to confirm if it got installed or not, it looks fine from here

````
opensips 19881  3641  0 11:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19882 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19883 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:05 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19884 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:01 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19885 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19886 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19887 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
opensips 19888 19881  0 11:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/sbin/opensips -P /var/run/opensips/opensips.pid -m 128 -M 8 -u opensips -g opensips
root     23310  4465  0 12:05 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto opensips```

Please help me, what is blocking me to access the same on web interface.
````

Answer (score 0):

Installing the "opensips-2.1.2" package will only provide the OpenSIPS SIP server, which will process the incoming SIP traffic.

The OpenSIPS Control Panel is a separate project, meant to be accessed via a web server, such as Apache or Nginx.  Its purpose is to help system administrators provision various data for OpenSIPS to work with.  See the available install options [here](http://controlpanel.opensips.org/download.php).